# I changed to developer mode, but i dont have developer options in backend PLEASE HELP

Tags: magento2, backend, admin-panel, developer-mode

I have version 2.2.7 with **nginx**

I changed from Production Mode to **Developer Mode**. But developer settings are not available. I cleaned the cache. I removed all folder with:

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static
sudo rm -rf var/cache
sudo rm -rf var/composer_home
sudo rm -rf var/generation
sudo rm -rf var/page_cache
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
```

BUT STILL NOT WORKING.

Comment: check your admin user role resources if all menu items is enabled for that specific user

Comment: I checked it is set on all ressources

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 + NGINX + REDIS + VARNISH + SSL Changing to Developer mode](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273460/magento-2-nginx-redis-varnish-ssl-changing-to-developer-mode)