# Magento 2 + NGINX + REDIS + VARNISH + SSL Changing to Developer mode

Tags: magento2, javascript, nginx, varnish, redis

in Production Mode everything is fine. 
When i change to Developer Mode i have this Problem

because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

So i start the  php  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and everthing is fine frontend and backend.

The Problem is: when i login to my backend, i dont have developer rights. I cant see developer configuration and when i change something on my theme it does not apply the changes.

So what do i do wrong ?

Comment: What changes do you make in theme? Have you enabled minification, merge and bundling?

Comment: No I did not. Do you think it is because of the cache ?

Comment: you have to clean all caches, opcache too.